# How can i add a fake base url in yii2

Tags: url, url-rewriting, yii2

I want to have a fake URL for the yii2 advanced application 
below is the sample I want to achieve

Home Page

> www.example.com/er45se5t

Users page

> www.example.com/er45se5t/users/index

Explanation:

Here er45se5t is a token or an identifier. I need this token to be present in URL for every request.

Solutions tried:

I tried to save token in session and set it and added it with all URLs

added these rules

```
'<token:\w+>' => 'site/index',
'<token:\w+>/<controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/index'
```

Problem

When I logout this session got cleared and cannot add this token to URL.

so after logging out, I want the URL to look like this

> www.example.com/er45se5t

or

> www.example.com/er45se5t/site/login

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add component named CustomUrlManager with content:

```
namespace frontend\components;

use yii\web\UrlManager;

class CustomUrlManager extends UrlManager
{
    public function createUrl($params)
    {
        $defaultToken='er45se5t';

        if( isset($params['token']) ){
            //you can add whatever here
            $token=$params['token'];
            unset($params['token']);
        } else {
            //you can add whatever here
            $token=$defaultToken;
        }

        $url = parent::createUrl($params);


        if( $url == '/' ){
            return '/'.$token;
        }else{
            return '/'.$token.$url;
        }
    }
}
```

And in config file as component:

```
'urlManager' => [
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
'showScriptName' => false,
'class'=>'frontend\components\CustomUrlManager',
'rules'=>[

]
```

],

And you can redirect www.example.com/ to some www.example.com/er45se5t on default controller